# Eclipse can't run specific project

Tags: eclipse

I have problem with Eclipse IDE. I can't run specific file. (all others works fine) When I try to run it, I get output of older project. I can't find name of that new project when I click arrow next to "run" button. 
Restarting Eclipse and computer doesn't help. I tried delete that project and make new - same. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the editor window there is run option click on it to run